# ECONNREFUSED when trying to use jsreport

Tags: node.js, jsreport

The following code:

```
var output = '<p>Hello</p>';
require("jsreport").render({
    template: {
      content: output
    }
}).then(function(out) {
    out.result.pipe(res);
   });
});
```

returns this error :

```
Error:  { [Error: Error during rendering report: connect ECONNREFUSED]
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 syscall: 'connect' }
```

I believe it's because it cannot connect to internal jsreport server, but don't know why. Any idea on how to debug it or why it happens ?

Comment: the port that app is trying to use is already in use...

Comment: I changed the port number to something not being used , it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the embedded jsreport to stand alone jsreport . So we use the remote client to connect to this stand-alone instance. Now it works ! I don't know why.